# Issue with JS regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression in order to check some text inserted in a `textarea`. Basically, when typing I check the number of words inserted. As special chars, only commas and full stop are allowed.

The problem is, for example, when I type `word,anotherword` my regex recognises only one word instead of two. I cannot find a good regex for it.

My current regex is:

```
val.match(/\S+[A-Za-z]/g
```

What shall I add? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `val.match(/\w+/g)`. `\S` matches any non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since `\S` matches any non-whitespace characters, and a comma, too, you should be using

```
val.match(/\w+/g)
```

A `\w` matches word characters, those in `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` ranges and a `_` (underscore).

Comment: Thanks. This works apart from 2 things. Firstly, when I first press the spacebar as first char in the textarea it returns null. Second, if I type --> word's  it considers that 2 words instead of one as it should be. Any idea?

Comment: The `\w+` does not match spaces, so `null` is correct, [there is no word in the text area](https://regex101.com/r/sP3zF5/1). This pattern [cannot match `-->`](https://regex101.com/r/sP3zF5/2) since `-` and `>` are not word characters.

Comment: Sorry there is a misunderstanding here. I'm not inserting "-->" in the textarea but "word's" ...I used the arrow to indicate the word on here :))  ahah ...here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1hxd4qdr/

Comment: I've sorted the aphostrope issue with this val.match(/[a-zA-Z']+/g).length. The only problem left is that when I first click on the space bar in the textarea I get a null pointer exception. How can I tell it to accept whitespaces before any words?

Comment: The null pointer exception happens because you can't call `.length` on `null`. One way to get around this is `(val.match(/[a-zA-Z']+/g) || "").length`.

Comment: If a match is failed, string.match returns null. Check for the null value as Nicholas shows and use `/\s*[a-z']+/gi` expression to match optional whitespace before the word.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract the words, or check if the entered text is of the correct format?

If the first, use js Array.split(",") and check that each word is ok.

Otherwise, I think this refer should do it:

`val.match(/^(\w+\,?)+$/);`

Use the ^ and $ to make sure it starts and end around the found correct format.

Comment: What I need is that any word in typed can have any whitespace before or after. Also, as I said, it can contain comma, full-stop or aphostrophe after itself like --> (word,word2  | word.word2 |  word's word2) and be considered one word still.